# N number of report whith different parameters

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am totaly begginer in DevExpress. I have N number of report (let's say around 100) with different parameters. Now I want to create solution which I will choose `parameters` and `report` it will display report in `Viewer`.
Since I have read about `DevExpress` but I couldnt find any example how to do this. Any idea or guidelines how to do this kind of  `Report`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your problem is very general. Please have a look at the Help Center how to ask.

Comment: What to look ? What how to ask ?

Comment: You can find the Help Center by using the question mark link at the top-right position of this site. There are explanations, which types of questions are answered by the members of stackoverflow.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer: [Set programatically the title to the viewer form in XtraReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401507/set-programatically-the-title-to-the-viewer-form-in-xtrareport)

```
public partial class ReportViewer : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
    public ReportViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Used when displaying a single report
    public void SetReport(XtraReport report)
    {
        this.printControl.PrintingSystem = report.PrintingSystem;
        report.CreateDocument();
        this.printControl.UpdatePageView();
    }

    // Used when displaying merged reports
    public void SetReport(PrintingSystem system)
    {
        this.printControl.PrintingSystem = system;
        this.printControl.UpdatePageView();
    }
}
```

So displaying a report goes like this:

```
ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
viewer.SetReport(new EmployeeReport());
viewer.Show();
```

[How to load a report to the Document Viewer at runtime](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/Ticket/Details/T473647/how-to-load-a-report-to-the-document-viewer-at-runtime)

Comment: Thanks, that's great example !